# C# DateTime subtraction hours from an DateTime Variable

Tags: c#, datetime, hour, date-arithmetic

I want to compare to dates like :

I have an Variable DateTime, and I want compare if the TIME of this variable is smaller than actual TIME ...

ex:

```
 Datetime DateT = new DateTime.Now; 

    string Myvariable = "13:00:36";
```

Comment: I want to have a cup of coffee ... Please read [FAQ] first.

Comment: Yummm...coffee!  @Marco, you'd need to convert your string variable to a DateTime using one of the various common methods (Google it) and then do the comparison...

Comment: But, How can I compare an VAriable in date time like this "2013-06-03 13:00:36"  with another date time variable with "13:00:36" ??

Comment: Either create a DateTime with just that Date, then add in just the Time portion so you can compare them as DateTimes; or extract just the time portions and compare them as @Damith has shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**DateTime.TryParseExact Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)  and [**DateTime.TimeOfDay Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) as below

```
string value = "13:00:36";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    if (dt.TimeOfDay > DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)
    {
        // greater than actual time 
    }
    else
    {
        // smaller than actual time
    }
}
```

Since you have time in string format it is difficult to compare. What you can do is convert it to Datetime by giving correct format string. Now you have two DateTime objects and you can get Time of those object by `TimeOfDay` property and compare..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `DateTime` variable instead? Something like this:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 13, 00, 36);
DateTime dateNow = new DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("T", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES")));
// Outputs 6:30:00
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("U", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
// Outputs Tuesday, January 1, 2013 13:00:36 PM 
Console.WriteLine(dateNow.ToString());
// Outputs the current date/time
```

Then you can create another DateTime and compare them as `DateTime` variable, not strings, although you can still output the values as strings using `date1.ToString()` function.

More info about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nevermind, there are more efficient solutions above. I was thinking about something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the time string as a DateTime instance:

```
 DateTime DateT = new DateTime.Now; 

 string Myvariable = "13:00:36";

 DateTime parsedTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    Myvariable, 
    "HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The `parsedTime` will have the time components (Hour, Minute, Second) as given in the string variable, **but it will have a different date**. The Year, Month and Day components are not present in the string, so they will default to the date of `DateTime.MinValue.Date`. In order to compare correctly, you need to **compare only the time parts**:

```
bool isParsedGreater = parsedTime.Hours > DateT.Hours 
    && parsedTime.Minutes > DateT.Minutes 
    && parsedTime.Seconds > DateT.Seconds;
```